# Why do types 'a and ''Z not match up in SML?

Tags: sml

I have the following recursive function:

```
fun tester (f:'a -> 'b, tl:(string * 'a * 'b) list) =
    case tl of
    [] => []
     | (t, c, e)::rest => 
       let val tr = f (c)
       in
           if tr <> (e)
           then ((t), (e), tr)::(tester (f, rest))
           else tester (f, rest)
       end;
```

When loading it I get "Error: operator and operand don't agree [UBOUND match]':

```
lec1test.sml:17.5-19.26 Error: operator and operand don't agree [UBOUND match]
  operator domain: ''Z * ''Z
  operand:         'b * 'Y
  in expression:
    tr <> e

uncaught exception Error
  raised at: ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:66.19-66.27
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:44.55
             ../compiler/TopLevel/interact/evalloop.sml:296.17-296.20
```

I have figured out that I think it has something with the generic binding of tr, but I can't see why that is a problem. I am assigning `tr`to a value of the function from `f`, which returns `'b`. I then compare the result with the last value in the tuple which also is of type `'b`. Can someone explain why this is giving me an error?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Not all types support the equality operators `=` and `<>`, only so-called *equality types*. For example, `int` or `string list` or `bool * unit` are equality types, but e.g. function types `t -> u` never are, because there is no reasonable (decidable) way to compare functions.

Values of a polymorphic type like `'a` are not equality types either, because the type variable can be instantiated by any type. To get a polymorphic type restricted to equality types, you need to write a type variable with a double tick, e.g. `''a`.

In your case, changing the first line to

```
fun tester (f : ''a -> ''b,  tl : (string * ''a * ''b) list) =
```

should fix it for you.